# Windows can't resolve raspberrypi domain name

Tags: windows, dns

I currently have a Raspberry Pi 4 set up on my home network, running Pi-hole. I also have a desktop on this network, dual booting Windows and Linux Mint. When I'm running Linux Mint, I can connect to the Pi via SSH without difficulty. When running Windows, I can't resolve the `raspberrypi` domain name, despite the Pi working as my DNS server:

```
> nslookup raspberrypi
Server:  raspberrypi
Address:  192.168.1.223

*** raspberrypi can't find raspberrypi: Non-existent domain

> nslookup raspberrypi.local
Server:  raspberrypi
Address:  192.168.1.223

*** raspberrypi can't find raspberrypi.local: Non-existent domain
```

I've tried flushing DNS on Windows with `ipconfig /flushdns`. I've also checked C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, there's nothing relevant there.

My Pi has a static IP, so I could use the raw IP or add an entry to my hosts file, but I'd like to know what's going on. Anyone know why I wouldn't be able to `nslookup` or otherwise resolve my Pi's hostname?

Comment: Start with https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?locale=en_GB and check your router / switch / APs support domain names

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with Windows - which has a non standard implementation of .local (depends on version).

This has **NOTHING** to do with the Pi (or DNS for that matter).

See [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

As Milliways said, this is not a RPi problem. Anyway, if you want to detect your RPi via it's hostname in Windows, you could do that after installing [Bonjour for Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?locale=es_ES). After installation completes, reboot windows and try again.

Good luck!